# How do I repair Steam?

Tags: software-installation, games, dpkg, steam

After I turned down my computer and came back, steam suddenly needed to update, and the games are gone.

I thought the paths to the actual files are gone, as the amount of space that the games take up my partition are still there, as shown by GParted.

So, I decided to reinstall Steam, which would only affect the launcher and leave the games right where they are. But now, I have this issue.

```
enter code heredpkg: error processing package steam (--configure):
package steam is not ready for configuration
cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Try with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure steam`

Comment: I get /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: steam is broken or not fully installed

Comment: reinstalling steam should resolve your problem. It does not affect the games you've already downloaded. `apt-get remove steam` or `dpkg -r steam`, then `apt-get install steam`

Answer (score -2):

GUI way to do it:

1. Go to software center and click installed on the top
2. Type `steam` into the search bar (without qoutes and spaces)
3. Click show technical items on the bottom
4. Delete all versions of Steam
5. Reinstall Steam **NOT using** the command line `sudo apt-get install steam`

Official steam (at my current date Jan 9 2015) was named *steam (steam-launcher)*